# Application Insights on Azure Stack Hub

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-stack

We are moving some services to privately hosted Azure stack (based on Azure Stack Hub), and I was wondering if "Application Insights" is available in Azure Stack Hub? On my App Service resources I can see the "Application Insights" menu item, but it is disabled, so I can't open it. Furthermore Application Insights is not available in the Marketplace. Is it a question of changing the configuration of the Azure Stack Hub setup, or is it simply not available in general on Azure Stack Hub?

Comment: According to the Microsoft documentation, Application Insights is not currently available on Azure Stack Hub. However, you can use Azure Monitor to monitor your applications and services on Azure Stack Hub. Azure Monitor provides similar functionality to Application Insights, including the ability to monitor performance, diagnose issues, and analyze usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with @Naveen that Application Insights is not currently available on Azure Stack Hub and you can use Azure Monitor to monitor your applications and services on Azure Stack Hub..

- **AFAIK Application Insights is not accessible through Azure Stack Hub.** Although Azure Stack Hub is an extension of Azure, it doesn't provide the entire range of services that the public Azure cloud delivers and one of them is Application insights. For up-to-date information regarding application insight feature in Azure Stack Hub you can check with azure Stack Hub Support team.
- As per this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-metrics-azure-data?view=azs-2206)  **a platform feature called Azure Monitor offers a centralised location for monitoring Azure resources**. You may visualise, query, route, archive, and perform other operations on metrics and logs originating from Azure resources using Azure Monitor. Utilising the Azure Stack Hub administrator site, you may manipulate this data.
  [image]
- An interactive, fully integrated solution called **Azure Monitor HCI Insights** provide information on the health, performance, and consumption of Azure Stack HCI clusters that are linked to Azure and registered with Azure Monitor.

  Thanks to @Saniya Islam for the useful documentation related to [Azure monitor HCI insights](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-stack-blog/announcing-the-general-availability-of-azure-monitor-hci/ba-p/3822091).